# ESlint parsing error "Unexpected token" on TypeScript cast operator "as"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint

Any occurrence of `as` operator gives `[eslint] [E] Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"` pointing to the place of `as`. Example code:

```
{error && <small className="invalid-feedback">{(error as any).message}</small>}
```

This cast to `any` is a workaround to some bug in `react-hooks-form`'s `useFormContext` function.

When I ignore the error and compile the app it works fine.

This happens in a standard unejected Create React App with latest TypeScript and react-scripts:

```
$ npm list -dev -depth 0
frontend@0.1.0 
├── eslint-plugin-flowtype@3.13.0
├── react-hot-loader@4.12.19
├── react-scripts@3.4.0
└── typescript@3.8.2
```

AFAIK there are no configuration files besides autogenerated `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Any ideas why this happens?

Answer (score 35):

I was running into a similar problem, and a simple fix that worked for me was the following.
I added this to my `package.json`:

```json
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
```

I noticed that `create-react-app --template typescript` generates a `package.json` with this in it.

Comment: FTR: this solution is specific for Create React Apps.

Answer (score 18):

I've found that the source of the problem was **misconfiguration of *Coc*** (intellisense engine for Vim8 & Neovim) and its environment. It was using wrong (**old**) installation of **eslint** from outside of my project. I had to correct *PATH* and make sure *workspace folders* are detected correctly.

**EDIT**: `react-scripts` based application with TypeScript support added by `npm install --save typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest` is not ready for linting .ts[x] source files by eslint. One have to manually configure it. I used this guide: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/docs/getting-started/linting/README.md and came up with following config (`.eslintrc.json`):

```
{
    "extends": [
        "standard",
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
    ],
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "plugins": [
        "@typescript-eslint"
    ],
    "settings": {
        "react": {
            "pragma": "React",
            "version": "detect",
            "flowVersion": "0.53"
        }
    },
    "overrides": [
        {
            "files": ["*.js", "*.jsx"],
            "rules": {
                "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": "off"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Which probably will need a lot of tuning.

Answer (score 5):

I was running into this issue while trying to use Jest with a tsx file with the `as` operator in it.  I solved the problem by doing two simple things:

1. Run `npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-typescript`
2. In your babel.config.js, in the presets array, add `'@babel/preset-typescript'` at the end.