# React.CSSProperties shows parsing error when used to insert css variables into App

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, react-css-modules

I am trying to use these variables in my scss file so that I can change my theme in the future directly from here. But it shows me parsing error, which was not there in the previous projects.

This is a React CRA project with typescript.

//App.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.scss";

const lightTheme = {
    "--primary": "#27AE60",
    "--text-primary": "#000000",
    "--background-primary": "#ffffff",
    "--background-secindary": "#fafafa",
} as React.CSSProperties;

const App = () => {
    return <div className="App" style={lightTheme}></div>;
};

export default App;
```

I can now use them as -

//App.scss

```
body {
color: var(--primary);
}
```

My package.json file -

```
{
    "name": "management-portal",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
        "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
        "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
        "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
        "@types/react": "^16.9.53",
        "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
        "react": "^17.0.1",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
        "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
        "sass": "^1.32.5",
        "typescript": "^4.0.3",
        "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    }
}
```

But it is throwing me this error ...

```
  Line 9:3:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"    

   7 |  "--background-primary": "#ffffff",
   8 |  "--background-secindary": "#fafafa",
>  9 | } as React.CSSProperties;
     |   ^
  10 | 
  11 | const App = () => {
  12 |  return <div className="App" style={lightTheme}></div>;
```

Although I expect the following result -
[Expected result in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoESy.jpg)

I have got a workaround for the error, which works fine. But I am not able to find my mistake in my earlier code. Here it is -

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.scss";

const lightTheme: any = {
    "--primary": "#27AE60",
    "--text-primary": "#000000",
    "--background-primary": "#ffffff",
    "--background-secindary": "#fafafa",
};

const App = () => {
    return <div className="App" style={lightTheme}></div>;
};

export default App;
```

Comment: The linter complains about the `as` cast, hence I would guess that you have to tell it that you're using TypeScript (like in [this bug report](https://github.com/eslint/typescript-eslint-parser/issues/455))

Comment: Can you add some more code from your application, because I reproduced this code in sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-breeze-ci1fo?file=/src/App.tsx
When i tries to do this in js file, that error showed. So see if you are actually using this in tsx file

Comment: Yes, I am using tsx only. And this error shows up, for more info, I am also attaching my package.json file -

Comment: @AakashSharma can you please make a reproducible live example (codesanbox or any you prefer

Comment: Check this out - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60547153/eslint-parsing-error-unexpected-token-on-typescript-cast-operator-as) @Andreas

Comment: [https://github.com/9267aakashsharma/management-portal](https://github.com/9267aakashsharma/management-portal)

You can clone it from here @MarioPetrovic

Comment: @AakashSharma i added an answer for your question. It's actually a really small fix. Good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I successfully cloned your repo and found out what was the cause of the above error.

You are missing `eslintConfig` property in `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "management-portal",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.53",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.32.5",
    "typescript": "^4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": { <----- This one
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Potentially you will need to add this `yarn add -D eslint-config-react-app`

It's a small fix, but this property is generated by CRA cli. Not sure why you are missing it since you used that command (Maybe your app was ejected or you are adding Typescript to your app ad hoc).

Comment: It is still not working for me, I have updated the package.json but it is showing the same error. Check here - [Erorr](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I69tClsIgrfpx5OrQh6ObQjRKXnqeooo/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Have you restarted your server after package.json change?
It is mandatory

Comment: yes, I have restarted my server. I know that.

Comment: It's really strange. I could reproduce your error and solve it with this solution. I will check if i have anything else installed that solves this form local npm

Comment: @AakashSharma try installing this package `eslint-config-react-app` yarn add -D eslint-config-react-app

Comment: I don't know why, but this worked. I re-installed the package and it's working now. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Hey, great. Glad it helped. Cheers!